# I am getting the following error when I am inserting a all the lines of a very large log file into ms sql server 2008

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

**1. The program continues to run for other lines but this error is just
    for some particular    lines . If there are 134789 lines to be
    inserted , then only around 133666 lines are inserted . The format
    of all the lines are same as it is in the log file .**

```
 *com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'In'.
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:792)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:689)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerStatement.java:642)
            at Access.insertIntoDatabase(Access.java:186)
            at appWindowLog$1thread1.run(appWindowLog.java:233)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)*
```

Comment: This is my insert query : 


String query = "INSERT INTO dbo.logs (Host, Mac, Name,Time, TimeZone, Request, status, size, Referer, SessionId) VALUES ('"+this.Host+"','"+this.Mac+"','"+this.Name+"','"+t+"','"+this.TimeZone+"','"+this.Request+"','"+this.status+"','"+this.size+"','"+this.Referer+"','"+this.SessionId+"');";

Comment: Please put your query in your question, that's the most important part. And make sure you read about SQL Injection.

Comment: 1. This query should have been an edit to your original post.
2. This is a terrible, terrible way of building SQL strings. Please read up on SQL injection as it's prone to massive security flaws and performance issues as it can't re-use query plans.
3. You probably have a keyword in your fields somewhere which is being interpretted by the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). Your log line probably contains unexpected `'` symbol that breaks your insert statement. If you use PreparedStatement it will escape parameters in a correct way.

Comment: Hello thanks for your prompt reply ... I am using : 
int up = this.stmt.executeUpdate(query);

Comment: Thank you so much .... All your help worked (SQL injection and Prepared Statement )

Answer (score 2):

You know, this is a beginner level tip:

FIND THE SQL STATEMENT WITH AN ERROR.

Seriously.

In the exception handler, print out the SQL and see what is wrong. It will give you the exact SQL that blows. Given the error message you basically have a SQL Injection like issue - something in a field needs escaping, which is an issue because you build the statement not using parameters (BAD BAD BAD).

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'In'.

IN (not INTO) is not a keyword that appears into your INSERT INTO ... VALUES... syntax, so something breaks out of it. For example with a string containing a ' - should not happen, but .... well ;) obviously it does.

When you found it, type "SQL Injection" into google and learn about it - runs along the same approach. You will never put SQL together like that any more (or deserve being fired when someone finds out).